# Getting previous month name - batch file

Tags: batch-file

I need to write a .bat file for backup process. Already, .bat file is running successfully in below format:

2013-12-08
2013-13-08
2013-14-08
.
.
.
2013-12-09
2013-13-09
2013-14-09

This takes more space in our server & we deleting the old files manually. So, i need a .bat to delete the previous month files automatically.

Answer (score 2):

The Batch file below assumes that the format displayed by `echo %date%` command is YYYY-DD-MM; if it is not, a small adjustment is needed.

**EDIT**: I modified the Batch file below in order to avoid the error reported in comment:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get the previous month
for /F "tokens=1,3 delims=-" %%a in ("%date%") do (
   set prevYear=%%a
   set month=%%b
)
if "%month:~0,1%" equ "0" set month=%month:~1%
set /A prevMonth=month-1
if "%prevMonth%" equ "0" (
   set /A prevMonth=12, prevYear-=1
)
if %prevMonth% lss 10 set prevMonth=0!prevMonth!

rem Delete the files of previous month
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=-" %%a in ('dir /B *.*') do (
   if %%c equ %prevMonth% del %prevYear%-%%b-%%c
)
```

Comment: this doesn't work, error message is `1! was unexpected at this time.`, better: `if "!month:~0,1!" equ "0"` (and I don't know why, this is `delayed expansion` ?). You need also a treatment for January, `00` is not valid :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [forfiles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc753551%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) command if you are on Windows Vista or up

```
forfiles /D -30 /P C:\your\backyup\folder\ /M *.bak /C "del @file "
```

if you're ok to remove 30 days old files, which is roughly a month but doesn't take into account current/previous month.

Comment: This will delete the files generated in the last 30 days, including the current month's file if it already exists.